# Can't pass two command line arguments that are filenames to functions

Tags: c, function, command, arguments, line

Project is large ~400 lines that's why I put it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/MfZ87K7H)

Only 3 functions needs two files to work

Here are their names

```
  graph_dim(&argv[1]); //GLOBAL PARAMETER NBR_OF_BINS GETS UPDATED IN THIS FUNCTION!!!

  FILE_graph_reading(&argv[1]); //PRINTS GRAPH ON SCREEN TOO!!!! 

  FILE_reading_global_params(&argv[2]);
```

That's on line 130-133.

This is what I get:

```
Usage: Complete_Test6 graph_filename parameters_filename
```

When I change if(argc != 2) to if(argc != 3) It is not showing that message but program still doesn't work. But it should automatically.

Message is:

```
Matrix is unequal. Exiting...
```

That's on line Line 441.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't need all those ampersands - just call `graph_dim(argv[1]);` and so on. Also, **turn on compiler warnings** - the compiler will then catch a lot of silly mistakes likes this for you.

Comment: @PaulR I tried that for all three functions and got this http://pastebin.com/mt5Q7KCp

Comment: OK - your code is a real mess, but it looks like maybe you should just be passing `argv` on its own. Turn on compiler warnings and learn to use your debugger. Also learn some general debugging strategies, like narrowing down a problem, divide and conquer, etc.

Comment: @PaulR how do I pass just argv on it's own?

Comment: That would be `graph_dim(argv)`, for example. Seriously though, you should probably get back to basics before you try and write any more code: read a decent book on C, learn how to debug, turn on compiler warnings and understand what they mean, otherwise your coding is only ever going to be random guesswork, with disastrous results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is actually need of passing address of every command line arguments..? Simply you can pass every arguments..

change these

```
graph_dim(&argv[1]); //GLOBAL PARAMETER NBR_OF_BINS GETS UPDATED IN THIS FUNCTION!!!

FILE_graph_reading(&argv[1]); //PRINTS GRAPH ON SCREEN TOO!!!! 

FILE_reading_global_params(&argv[2]);
```

to

```
   graph_dim(argv[1]); //GLOBAL PARAMETER NBR_OF_BINS GETS UPDATED IN THIS FUNCTION!!!

   FILE_graph_reading(argv[1]); //PRINTS GRAPH ON SCREEN TOO!!!! 

  FILE_reading_global_params(argv[2]);
```

Take following program as reference, I hope  this will help you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void grap(char * v);

int main( int c, char ** v)
{
if(c!=2)
return;
grap(v[1]);
}

void grap(char* v)
{
printf("%s\n",v);
}
```

Comment: Nope, it's not working, gives a lot of errors when I try to compile it. Here are the messages: http://pastebin.com/mt5Q7KCp

Well, I am passing filenames to some functions.

Comment: @EsoTeric I couldn't able to see your link.. So, can u please mention at least functions and errors

Comment: `C:\C\C++\Project\Complete_Test6.c: In function 'main':
C:\C\C++\Project\Complete_Test6.c:131:3: warning: passing argument 1 of 'graph_dim' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   graph_dim(argv[1]); //GLOBAL PARAMETER NBR_OF_BINS GETS UPDATED IN THIS FUNCTION!!!`

Comment: @EsoTeric I think this is function calling.. How you are catching ..? Can You mention please..??

Comment: @EsoTeric: The message on line 6 (in pastebin) says the function prototype is `void graph_dim(char* argv[]);`. Looks like it wants you to pass The whole command line. Use `graph_dim(argv)'. That will get you past that error... I would actually change `graph_dim(.)` to taking a `char*name` rather than `char* argv[]`

Comment: @DanAllen I tried this:   
  `graph_dim(&argv[0]);`

  `FILE_graph_reading(&argv[0]);`

  `FILE_reading_global_params(&argv[0]);`

And it worked.Don't know why but it works

Comment: `graph_dim(&argv[0])` is exactly the same as `graph_dim(argv)`, which is what I suggested earlier...